# query string in classic asp code to catch integer values

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

I have written below code piece that is supposed to search from DB based on two Parameters

1. Integer value(ID of a SHIP)
2. String value(SHIP name).

But with the following code I am able to get data from the DB using the SHIP name i.e using the 2nd case. But unable to search the data using the ID of the SHIP.

Following is the code snippet. Any help on these is highly appreciated.

```
nIMO = sql_ship_friendly(request.querystring("nIMO"))
if IsNumeric(nIMO) = false then
    nIMO = ""
else
    nIMO = cInt(nIMO)
end if

sVessel = sql_ship_friendly(UCase(request.querystring("sVessel")),10)


if not nIMO = "" then   

    'search based on vessel id




sql = "SELECT IMO_NBR, VESSEL_NM, COALESCE(SHIP_TYP,'0') AS SHIP_TYP, COALESCE(DWT_WT, 0) AS DWT_WT, COALESCE(YEAR_BUILT_NBR, 0) AS YEAR_BUILT_NBR FROM RSP_VESSEL_VW WHERE ACTIVE_IND='Y' AND IMO_NBR = 7723948"
    Set db1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    db1.Open GV_VIEW_DB_String 
    Set rs = db1.Execute(sql)
    Set dbl = nothing "

elseif not sVessel = "" then

    'search based on vessel number


sql = "SELECT IMO_NBR, VESSEL_NM,  COALESCE(SHIP_TYP,'0') AS SHIP_TYP, COALESCE(DWT_WT, 0) AS DWT_WT, COALESCE(YEAR_BUILT_NBR , 0) AS YEAR_BUILT_NBR FROM RSP_VESSEL_VW WHERE VESSEL_NM LIKE '"&SVESSEL&"%' AND ACTIVE_IND='Y'"
```

> ' response.write sql         Set db1 =
>   Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")       db1.Open GV_VIEW_DB_String 
>         Set rs = db1.Execute(sql)       Set dbl = nothing

Answer (score 0):

if your first case you have placed following

> sql = "SELECT IMO_NBR, VESSEL_NM, COALESCE(SHIP_TYP,'0') AS SHIP_TYP,
>   COALESCE(DWT_WT, 0) AS DWT_WT, COALESCE(YEAR_BUILT_NBR, 0) AS
>   YEAR_BUILT_NBR FROM RSP_VESSEL_VW WHERE ACTIVE_IND='Y' AND IMO_NBR =
>   7723948"

but I can see you are using the **nIMO** perameter in query. Put it and you should get result..

You can use it like AND IMO_NBR = nIMO or likewise.

Comment: I am using SQL qry like this: sql = "SELECT IMO_NBR, VESSEL_NM, COALESCE(SHIP_TYP,'0') AS SHIP_TYP, COALESCE(DWT_WT, 0) AS DWT_WT, COALESCE(YEAR_BUILT_NBR, 0) AS YEAR_BUILT_NBR FROM RSP_VESSEL_VW WHERE ACTIVE_IND='Y' AND IMO_NBR = &nIMO".....but this is not woking ..then I tries to execute it by hardcoding nIMO in the sql..that also doesnot worked...@Jigar Panda

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is no where on your SQL statement that use nIMO variable as your search criteria. Forget about using IsNumeric(nIMO) = false... Use isNull function instead.  Try this.

```
if not isnull( request.querystring("nIMO")) then
    nIMO = cInt(nIMO)
    sql = "SELECT IMO_NBR, VESSEL_NM, COALESCE(SHIP_TYP,'0') AS SHIP_TYP," &_
          "COALESCE(DWT_WT, 0) AS DWT_WT, COALESCE(YEAR_BUILT_NBR, 0) AS " &_
          "YEAR_BUILT_NBR FROM RSP_VESSEL_VW WHERE ACTIVE_IND='Y' AND " &_
          "IMO_NBR =" & nIMO
    ...
    ...
    ...
 end if
```